# Connecting Azure Blob Container to Power BI Service

Tags: powerbi, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, powerbi-datasource

I am was tasked with importing some data to power BI service from an azure container... i was given the Query to import the data. However the query only imports a single file at a time and you have have to import and append each file to your data flow. Is there a way to import the entire folder eg the combine and load option on power bi desktop, when connecting to local files.

Query steps below:

Step one > I know how to connect to the blob: *=xml.tables(web.contents( "https://********** & ************** & **********")*

Step two > this seems to be the step that references a single file: *=Table.Addcolumn(source, "BinaryFiles", each Web.contents("https://**********************.xlsx?********************" *

i believe if i can get that second step to show all the files in the folder/blob then i can combine them because they are the same schema. When i remover the specific file name from the string i get the following error :

DataSource.Error: Web.Contents failed to get contents from "https://************************" (404) The specified blob does not exist.

I can't share the detailed strings due to privacy reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving a Not Found error, as described by the code and by the description [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-error-codes).

Since I cannot see your URIs, I am not sure, but I think that, despite the change you made to the URI, you keep trying to get a blob, and that is why the service tells something like "a blob with such identification does not exist/is not found". Because, in this case, what you really want is to get all the blobs inside a specific blob container, right?

According to the Blob Service REST API [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-rest-api), it's not possible to get all blobs from a container in bulk, with only one request. What seems to be possible is to [get the list of blobs in a container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs), go through the list and [get each blob individually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob) :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do that with json files in Blob storage:

```
//Create custom function called "Transform file" first:
let
  Query = (Parameter as binary) => let
    #"Imported Text" = Table.FromColumns({Lines.FromBinary(Parameter,null,null,1252)}),
    #"Parsed JSON" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Imported Text",{},Json.Document)
in
    #"Parsed JSON"
in
  Query


//Then connect to blob container:
let
    Source = AzureStorage.Blobs("https://<yourStorageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net"),
    Navigation = Source{[Name = "<yourBlobContainerName>"]}[Data],
    #"Invoke custom function" = Table.AddColumn(Navigation, "Transform file", each #"Transform file"([Content])),
    #"Removed other columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Invoke custom function", {"Transform file"}),
    #"Expanded Transform file" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed other columns", "Transform file", {"Column1"}, {"Column1"})
in
    #"Expanded Transform file"
```